# Constructor with optional parameters

Tags: c++, qt

I have created a subclass of `QLineEdit` in Qt and I want to give the users the ability to set a few optional parameters when initializing/creating the control. I know this is handled in the way I define the constructor of the widget.

However I would like to make these parameters optional, so if the user decides not to define them, the constructor will use the default values I have set. For example, if the user does not define `PathMode` in the constructor in the code below, it will default to `LineEditPath::PathMode::ExistingFile`. I am not sure how to do this.

If the correct approach is to have multiple constructors, I am fine with that. It just seems redundant to have the initialization list in every constructor.

Here is my current code:

*.h*

```
class LineEditPath : public QLineEdit
{
    ...
    explicit LineEditPath(QWidget *parent = nullptr);
    explicit LineEditPath(PathMode pathMode, QWidget *parent = nullptr);
    ...
}
```

*.cpp*

```
LineEditPath::LineEditPath(QWidget *parent) : QLineEdit(parent),
    button(new QPushButton("...", this)),
    dialog(new QFileDialog(this)),
    defaultDir(QStandardPaths::writableLocation(QStandardPaths::HomeLocation)),
    m_pathMode(ExistingFile)
{
    init();
}

LineEditPath::LineEditPath(LineEditPath::PathMode, QWidget *parent) : QLineEdit(parent),
    button(new QPushButton("...", this)),
    dialog(new QFileDialog(this)),
    defaultDir(QStandardPaths::writableLocation(QStandardPaths::HomeLocation)),
    m_pathMode(ExistingFile)
{
    init();
    // Additional stuff for this constructor...
}
```

Do I need to have multiple constructors or I can just have one constructor and somehow set the default values?

Comment: You may be interested in [delegating constructors](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/initializer_list#Delegating_constructor). You only have to implement the most complete (argument-wise) constructor and have other ones delegate to it, passing default values where necessary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this case, just give pathmode a default too

```
class LineEditPath : public QLineEdit
{
    ...
    explicit LineEditPath(PathMode pathMode = default_or_sentinel_value, QWidget *parent = nullptr);
    ...
}
```

And remove the other constructor. Now the difference between default and sentinel value here would be, that default value you will just use, and not care if it was supplied by the user or by the compiler as default. This is probably what you want here, I suppose.

Sentinel value would be special value such as some "null" value, which can't be used like other values. You would have something like `if(pathMode.isNull()) {...handle special case...} else {...use pathMode...}` to handle it correctly.

For a more complex case, you might want to look at [delegating constructors](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/initializer_list#Delegating_constructor) (link  copied from comment of  François Andrieux).